# Separating out values in column inside Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-like

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have table which stores information about whom to send notification and one of column stored subscriber ids like 3,4,5 in this way.

I am passing `userid` to my stored procedure and I want to return result set if passed user id is contain inside column data.

Like if I am passing 4 and my subscriber IDs are 3,4,5 since 4 is present i need to select that row.

```
        SELECT  twfNotification.NotificationMessage ,  

        FROM    twfNotification  

        WHERE @iSubscribedID in (twfNotification.SubscribedUsers)
```

'twfNotification.SubscribedUsers -> nvarchar'

twfNotification.SubscribedUsers had data like 3,4,5  and i am passing @iSubscribedID = 4 this is in SP.  so now i have to find out if passed @iSubscribedID i.e 4 is present in twfNotification.SubscribedUsers column.

if direct than we can do @iSubscribedID = twfNotification.SubscribedUsers, but twfNotification.SubscribedUsers column stored values like 3,4,5 comma separated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NORMALIZATION of TABLES` is the better way to do this.

Alternate solution:

```
SELECT a.NotificationMessage 
FROM twfNotification a
WHERE ',' + a.SubscribedUsers + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @iSubscribedID) + ',%'
```

Comment: hanks a lot.. this one is perfect… what i want.